# Write a Bash script to read file, add to list, search for Github repos and download specific file to a folder

Tags: bash, shell, github

I'm trying to write a Bash script in which I have to read a text file that contains some names. For example,

```
abc-analytics-api-v1_0
abc-billing-api-v2_0
abc-shipping-api-v1_0
```

I need to read this file and add to a list. Then I need to iterate through the list and extract the names (analytics,billing,shipping) and version (1,2,1). The next step is to find list of repos in Github Enterprise that belong to those components abc-api-{component}-dist. For example,

```
abc-api-analytics-dist
abc-api-billing-dist
abc-api-shipping-dist
```

These repos have similar folder structure. They have a folder that is named after version (1.0 for analytics, 2.0 for billing). I select the latest tag and then the path goes {version}.0/abc-apigee-{component}-dist/def. There is this file swagger-{component}.json. I need to download this json file for every repo and put it in a folder.
I wrote a script (unfinished) to just get the file path of the JSON. But I can't get the text file to read properly. I have already authorized Github credentials.

```
#!/bin/bash

list_file="envi.txt"
proxy_list=$(cat "$list_file")

for proxy in $proxy_list; do
  component=$(echo $name | sed 's/abc-\(.*\)-api-v.*_0/\1/')
  version=$(echo $name | sed 's/abc-.*-api-v\([0-9]\+\)_0/\1/')

  repo_name="abc-api-${component}-dist"
  repo_list=$(gh repo list --json name --jq ".[] | select(.name | startswith(\"${repo_name}\")) | .name")

  for repo in $repo_list; do
    # Find the latest tag of the repository and switch to it
    tag=$(gh api "/repos/company/${repo}/tags" --paginate --jq '[.[].name] | map(select(test("^v[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)*$"))) | sort_by(split(".")[].|tonumber) | last')
    gh repo clone "OneCompany/${repo}" -- --branch "$tag"

    # Step 5: Find the Swagger file path
    swagger_path=$(find . -name '*.json' -path '${version}.0/abc-apigee-'"${component}"'-dist/def/*swagger*.json' -print -quit)

    if [ -n "$swagger_path" ]; then
      # To download swagger file to local folder
  done
done
```

Comment: Where is the `$name` variable coming from?  Should that be `$proxy` instead?

Comment: You might also consider changing your outer `for` loop to a `while` loop.  Something like: `while read -r proxy ; do echo "$proxy" ; done < envi.txt`

Comment: You could then split each $proxy into an array via `IFS='-'; read -ra arr <<<"$proxy"` Then extract component and version from the array: `component="${arr[1]}"`  and `version="${arr[3]:1:1}"` This would avoid the less efficient sub shell calls to sed.